# How to parse this XML ajax response?

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, parsing

I am trying to parse some data with jQuery retrieving by ajax from a Java servlet or action. This is my worst week, everything goes bananas. Here it is my XML response:

```
<ajax-response>
    <response>
        <item>
            <name>ok</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>menuDiv</name>
            <value> Some HTML Menu</value>
        </item>
    </response>
</ajax-response>
```

And I am trying to get just the "menuDiv" value that is "Some HTML" :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: basePath+'mostrarMenu.do',
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml
});

function parseXml (xml) {
    var menu = $(xml).find("item");
    menu.each(function(i, value) {
        alert(value[0]);
        if (value == 'menuDiv') {
            alert("Esto es el menudiv:"+value);
        }

        if (( value != null ) || ( value != '') || ( value != ' ')) {
            $('#menuDiv').append(value);
        } 
        else 
            alert ("anda el else");
    });
```

`alert(value[0]);` and `if ( value == 'menuDiv') {` returns nothing, and the last `if` makes the menu visible, but with the others items too, like a `true` word appearing before a handsome menu.

Any help or recommendation would be very appreciated. Thanks.

### EDIT 2:

With this function, now I am getting plain text (not rendered html) and all "< items >":

```
function parseXml (xml) {
        var menu = $(xml).find("item");
        menu.each(function(i, value){
            if(( value != null ) || ( value != '') || ( value != ' ')){
                $('#menuDiv').append($(value));
            } else alert ("anda el else");
        });
     }
    }
```

**I have change dataType: 'html' and my menu is visible, but I keep on trying to select just one ITEM on my XML and not all of them...**

Comment: Can you parse it into json server side before dispatching a result set? Might make it easier in the long run.

Comment: @MetalFrog has a great idea.  JSON is so much easier to parse with JavaScript.  But if not, someone will come along who can answer :)  Great question! +1

Comment: I will try that, but I think I wont make it

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is that when you do `find("item")`, what's returned is the whole subtree:

```
    <item>
        <name>ok</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </item>
```

So your loop needs to change to:

```
if ($(value).find("name")[0].innerHTML == 'menuDiv') {
    alert("Esto es el menudiv:"+value);
}
```

The value "Some HTML Menu" can then be obtained in `value.find("value")[0].innerHTML`

I'm not doing any error checking here (specifically, I'm assuming that the `find` returns a non-null array with at least one element) but you can add that on your own.

Comment: I think that I have tried that before and it returns value.find() is not a function. I will try again and tell what happens

Comment: Hmm when I tested it, I stored the elements of menu as separate variables and ran .find() on them. Will get back to you shortly.

Comment: Yes me too, I made a variable: `var allow = value.find("name")[0].innerHTML` and then firebug throws me value.find() is not a function...

Comment: I just edited my answer - you have to run `find` on `$(value)` not `value`.

Comment: That´s working. But I am getting the <!--[CDATA[menuDiv]]-->, what is wrong with that? How can I avoid this Cdata?

Comment: Is that just in Firebug or on an actual execution? I don't get a CDATA tag ... (testing in Chrome)

Comment: in both. I have fixed this by "hardcoding" (I could say) the IF: `var setere = $(value).find("name")[0].innerHTML;
if ( setere == '<!--[CDATA[menuDiv]]-->') { `. I have found that CDTA came from server like: `<response><item><name><![CDATA[ok]]></name><value><![CDATA[true]]></value>`

Comment: Yes it is working, but the problem is that after menu, I have a beatiful set of characters: ]]> , because it is the enclosure of the CDTA that came inside value tag, containing menu. Is there any Jquery method to get what is inside CDATA? or will I have to create some parse function?

Comment: Sorry .. I guess you'll have to write a small parsing function.

Comment: I know, and because innerHTML is not working in internet explorer...it crash before alert 1: `function parseXml(xml) {
  var menu = jQuery(xml).find("item");
  alert("0");
     menu.each(function(i, value) {
      alert("1");
         var setere = jQuery(value).find("name")[0].innerHTML;
         alert("1");
         if ( setere == '<!--[CDATA[menuDiv]]-->') {
          jQuery('#menuDiv').append(jQuery(value).find("value")[0].innerHTML);
         }
  });
  
 }`